# Not all code paths return a value (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, return-path

```
document.getElementById('search_field').onkeypress = function(e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13') {
            window.location.href = '/search/?s=' + $('#search_field').val();
            return false;
        } 
    };
```

The last bracket show me an error, not all code paths return a value, what seems to be problem here ?
Thanks

Comment: this is not jquery... its pure js code except  $('#search_field').val()

Comment: Whatever tool you're using that's showing you that is going to have trouble with a LOT of JavaScript code. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById('search_field').onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode == '13') {
    window.location.href = '/search/?s=' + $('#search_field').val();
    return false;
  } 
  return true;
};
```

More... I think that you may not use both pure javascript and jquery

So you'd rather choose between

- JAVASCRIPT :

  ```
    document.getElementById('search_field').onkeypress = function(e) {
          if (!e) e = window.event;
          var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
          if (keyCode == '13') {
              window.location.href = '/search/?s=' + document.getElementById('search_field').value;
              return false;
          } 
        return true;
      };
  ```
- JQUERY

  ```
    $( "#search_field" ).keypress(function( event ) {
      if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = '/search/?s=' + $(this).val();
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
  ```

Comment: always returning false will cause his textbox to not update for other keypresses. He wants to redirect onEnter so only the enter keypress should return false.

Comment: @Kristof The problem is not so clear... What we know it only that the function does't always return something... He does not talk about any textbox, does he ? !

Comment: He does not but he is binding a function to the onkeypress of an element called search_field. I'd say it's safe to assume the search field is in fact a search field where users can enter a search value after which they can press enter, no?

Comment: @Kristof I am agree with you. So you are agree with my correction : `return true` for any other keycode.

Answer (score 2):

End your function with `return true.`

If any other key then 13 is pressed the flow should just continue normally.

Comment: `return undefined` would be more in keeping with the existing code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought all the functions in js returns undefined by default. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Yoda: That's *effectively* correct. The specification actually differentiates between multiple "results" of a function call: A throw, a return value, or no return value. But it's just a spec thing, because the result of a call expression (an actual call to a function) that doesn't throw always has a result, and that result is `undefined` if the function doesn't return something specific.

Comment: The "error" you receive is just a warning. You created a function which has an outcome with no return value. In your case this will work but if others would depend on this function the behavior can be unexpected, therefor the warning.

Answer (score -1):

Ignore your tool. Event handlers do not have to return a value in every occasion, it is fine if only a particular path does `return false`.